# Broken GLSL Spinlock/GLSL Locks Compendium

Tags: opengl, atomic, spinlock

I have a setup where I need to lock, read some data, process, write some data, and then unlock.  To this end, I made a locking texture as a `layout(r32ui) coherent uniform uimage2D`.  The critical section's data is declared similarly.

Unfortunately, all my attempts at a spinlock don't prevent race conditions, leading to incorrect results.  I tried several different approaches.

I thought I'd collect all the information I could find on GLSL locking, along with my results (GTX 580M).  I have added a Community Wiki answer with this exhaustive list.  I would appreciate edits/comments about possible issues each presents, ultimately creating a list of valid approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have standardized the locking texture to be `img0`.

## Lock Type 1:

Thread warps have a shared program counter.  If a single thread grabs the lock, the other threads in the warp will still be stuck in the loop.  In practice, this compiles but results in a deadlock.

Examples: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809421/glsl-spinlock-never-terminates), [OpenGL.org](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/180916-using-spinlock-to-control-image-read-writes)

```
while (imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,1u)==1u);

//<critical section>
memoryBarrier();

imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,0);
```

---

## Lock Type 2:

To work around the issue of type 1, one instead writes conditionally.  In the below, I have sometimes written the loop as a do-while loop, but a while loop doesn't work correctly either.

### Lock Type 2.1:

The first thing one tries is a simple loop.  Apparently due to buggy optimizations, this can result in a crash (I haven't tried recently).

Example: [NVIDIA](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526793/glsl-loop-39-break-39-instruction-not-executed/)

```
bool have_written = false;
while (true) {
    bool can_write = (imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,1u)!=1u);

    if (can_write) {
        //<critical section>
        memoryBarrier();

        imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,0);
        break;
    }
}
```

### Lock Type 2.2:

The above example uses `imageAtomicExchange(...)`, which might not be the first thing one tries.  The most intuitive is `imageAtomicCompSwap(...)`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work due to buggy optimizations.  It (should be) otherwise sound.

Example: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820066/glsl-spinlock-only-mostly-works)

```
bool have_written = false;
do {
    bool can_write = (imageAtomicCompSwap(img0,coord,0u,1u)==0u);

    if (can_write) {
        //<critical section>
        memoryBarrier();

        imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,0);
        have_written = true;
    }
} while (!have_written);
```

### Lock Type 2.3:

Switching back from `imageAtomicCompSwap(...)` to `imageAtomicExchange(...)` is the other common variant.  The difference with 2.1 is the way the loop is terminated.  This doesn't work correctly for me.

Examples: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652862/glsl-semaphores), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820066/glsl-spinlock-only-mostly-works)

```
bool have_written = false;
do {
    bool can_write = (imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,1u)!=1u);

    if (can_write) {
        //<critical section>
        memoryBarrier();

        imageAtomicExchange(img0,coord,0);
        have_written = true;
    }
} while (!have_written);
```